# Searching using SOLR on multiple fields

Tags: apache, solr

I have two requirements for my SOLR implementation:

1. I need to be able to search on multiple fields at the same time (preferably with field boosting). This is possible using dismax parser.
2. I also have a specific set of indexed fields (example gender field). I need to be able to apply such specific filters (example: select?q=david&gender:male&status:married). As per my understanding of dismax, this is not possible.

Please suggest if the second requirement can be handled using dismax (or edismax)? For now i am forced to use standard query parser, even though i really liked dismax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from using dismax or edismax. Use [`qf`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#qf_.28Query_Fields.29) to tell it which fields to search by default, and use [`fq`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) to apply queries that act as filters.

```
/select?q=david&fq=gender:male&fq=status:married&qf=name^10 address^3
```

[Filter Queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) doesn't affect score, and will be cached separately. If you always filter on both gender and status, you could combine them to get a single query cache instead (`fq=gender:male AND status:married`).